# How i graphql subscription in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-router, apollo-client

I'm developing an application using a GraphQL client and React. In the main directory, I have a section where events are listed, and in the .../new directory, I have a form to add new events. When I add an event using the GraphQL Playground or by connecting to the .../new directory in a new tab, the list on the main page gets updated. However, if I use React Router to navigate to the .../new directory and add an event, the event list on the main page does not get updated."

EventList.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION, GET_EVENTS } from "./queries";
import { List, Divider } from "antd";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import Loading from "../../components/Loading";
import EventCounter from "../../components/EventCounter";

function EventList() {
    const { loading, error, data, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(GET_EVENTS);

    useEffect(() => {
        subscribeToMore({
            document: EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION,
            updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
                console.log(prev, subscriptionData);
                if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
                return {
                    events: [...prev.events, subscriptionData.data.eventCreated],
                };
            },
        });
    }, [subscribeToMore]);

    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="counter">
                <EventCounter />
            </div>

            <div className={styles.scrollableDiv} id="scrollableDiv">
                <List>
                    <InfiniteScroll dataLength={data.events.length} scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv" endMessage={<Divider plain>It is all, nothing more </Divider>}>
                        <List
                            dataSource={data.events}
                            renderItem={(item) => (
                                <List.Item key={item.id}>
                                    <List.Item.Meta
                                        title={
                                            <Link className={styles.listItemTitle} to={`/event/${item.id}`}>
                                                {item.title}
                                            </Link>
                                        }
                                        description={
                                            <Link className={styles.listItemDesc} to={`/event/${item.id}`}>
                                                {item.desc}
                                            </Link>
                                        }
                                    />
                                    <div className={styles.date}>{`${item.date} / ${item.from}-${item.to}`}</div>
                                </List.Item>
                            )}></List>
                    </InfiniteScroll>
                </List>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default EventList;
```

FormComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, DatePicker, Form, Input, Row, Select, TimePicker } from "antd";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import moment from "moment";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import { CREATE_EVENT, GET_LOCATIONS, GET_USERS } from "./queries";

function FormComponent() {
    const [addEvent, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_EVENT);

    const { loading: locationsLoading, error: locationsError, data: locationsData } = useQuery(GET_LOCATIONS);
    const locationsArray = [];
    if (!locationsLoading && !locationsError && locationsData) {
        locationsData.locations.forEach((item) => {
            const data = {
                value: item.id,
                label: item.name,
                title: "location_id",
            };
            locationsArray.push(data);
        });
    }

    const { loading: userLoading, error: userError, data: userData } = useQuery(GET_USERS);
    const usersArray = [];
    if (!userLoading && !userError && userData) {
        userData.users.forEach((item) => {
            const data = {
                value: item.id,
                label: item.username,
                title: "user_id",
            };
            usersArray.push(data);
        });
    }

    const [form] = Form.useForm();

    const disabledDate = (current) => {
        return current && current <= moment().startOf("day");
    };

    const handleFormSubmit = async (values) => {
        const data = {
            title: values.title,
            desc: values.desc,
            date: `${values.date.$y}-${values.date.$M + 1}-${values.date.$D}`,
            from: `${values.hours[0].$H < 9 ? "0" + values.hours[0].$H : values.hours[0].$H}:${values.hours[0].$m < 9 ? "0" + values.hours[0].$m : values.hours[0].$m}`,
            to: `${values.hours[1].$H < 9 ? "0" + values.hours[1].$H : values.hours[1].$H}:${values.hours[1].$m < 9 ? "0" + values.hours[1].$m : values.hours[1].$m}`,
            location_id: values.location_id,
            user_id: values.user_id,
        };
        await addEvent({
            variables: {
                data: data,
            },
            onCompleted: form.resetFields(),
        });
    };

    return (
        <Row>
            <Form className={styles.form} labelCol={{ span: 4 }} wrapperCol={{ span: 24 }} form={form} onFinish={handleFormSubmit}>
                <Form.Item label="Title" name="title" required rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter title" }]}>
                    <Input placeholder="Please enter title" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Description" name="desc" required rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter description" }]}>
                    <Input.TextArea placeholder="Please enter description" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Date" name="date" required rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please enter date" }]}>
                    <DatePicker placeholder="Please select a date" style={{ width: "100%" }} disabledDate={disabledDate} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="hours" label="Event Hours" required>
                    <TimePicker.RangePicker style={{ width: "100%" }} placeholder={["Select start time", "Select end time"]} format={"HH:mm"} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="Location" name="location_id" required rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select a location" }]}>
                    <Select placeholder="Please select a location" options={locationsArray} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item label="User" name="user_id" required rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select a user" }]}>
                    <Select placeholder="Please select a user" options={usersArray} />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </Row>
    );
}

export default FormComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apollo Client's Cache Update.
 When you add an event using the `addEvent` mutation in the `FormComponent`, you can manually update the Apollo Client cache to include the new event, so when you navigate back to the `EventList` component, it will re-render with the updated data.

```js
await addEvent({
    variables: {
        data: data,
    },
    update: (cache, { data: { addEvent } }) => {
        const { events } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_EVENTS });
        cache.writeQuery({
            query: GET_EVENTS,
            data: { events: events.concat([addEvent]) },
        });
    },
    onCompleted: form.resetFields(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem like this thank you very much

```
await addEvent({
                variables: {
                    data: values,
                },
                update: (cache, { data: { addEvent} }) => {
                    const events = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_EVENTS });
                    cache.writeQuery({
                        query: GET_EVENTS,
                        data: { events: [addEvent, ...events.events] },
                    });
                },
                onCompleted: navigate("/"),
            });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).